# Is there a tool for finding common references among multiple papers?

Tags: citations, reference-managers

My question is relatively straightforward. Is there a tool that takes multiple papers, reads through them and figures out which other papers these input papers refer to, and see the most commonly cited papers as references among those input papers?

Comment: Related: [Are there tools to find a subset of references shared by two or more publications?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/49884/17254) It doesn't currently answer your question, but it seems a good solution to your problem would apply also to the other.

Comment: You want to analyze a [citation graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_graph). Knowing the terminology should help in your search.

Answer (score 1):

There are citation manager packages which may provide some of what you need when you tell them the papers you are interested in.

https://guides.lib.uchicago.edu/c.php?g=297307&p=1984557

Answer (score 0):

Citation Gecko can do this for some areas: https://citationgecko.azurewebsites.net/

1. You search for the papers you are looking at and add them as seed papers.
2. Then the tool shows you common citations and the like for the papers you've added as seed papers.

But its ability to do this strongly depends on what papers it is able to find in Step 1.